# Shape Drawable is always gray

Tags: android, drawable

Using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Every time I set it as a background for any view it is always turns the background gray.

The xml is in res/drawable and I have tried both methods used in the guide.

Can someone shed some light on why it isnt working.

Comment: Could you show how do you use this shape? It works for me.

Comment: This xml will work fine...The problem may be in the part you applied it..

Comment: I copied the examples from the guide and used it in an existing project. I have one activity and two fragments, I copied the textview from the example and used it in my fragments AND the activity.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't know how I fixed it but I copied my layouts, deleted them, pasted them back in then cleaned the project (I do this often) and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00FFBB"
        android:endColor="#FFEEAA"

      />
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

[image]